# "font-display: optional" doesn't work in Chrome in Next.js and Emotion project

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, font-face, emotion

I have a strange case of `font-display: optional` not working in Chrome browser (`Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)`).

Few words about the project - it's [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) app with SSR and using [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) for styling.

Here's an example of how fonts are used in the app:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import { Global, css } from '@emotion/core';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';

import theme from './path/to/custom/theme';

export default class CustomApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Global
          styles={css`
            /* latin-ext */
            @font-face {
              font-family: 'Zen Tokyo Zoo';
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
              font-display: optional;
              src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/zentokyozoo/v1/NGSyv5ffC0J_BK6aFNtr6sRvwaRkREW-emmbxg.woff2)
                format('woff2');
              unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020,
                U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }
            /* latin */
            @font-face {
              font-family: 'Zen Tokyo Zoo';
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
              font-display: optional;
              src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/zentokyozoo/v1/NGSyv5ffC0J_BK6aFNtr6sRvwapkREW-emk.woff2)
                format('woff2');
              unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC,
                U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122,
                U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }

            body {
              font-weight: 400;
              font-family: 'Zen Tokyo Zoo', Monaco, sans-serif;
              font-feature-settings: 'kern';
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
              -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
              text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            }
          `}
        />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Example GIF (notice how font is changing despite being optional and cache being disabled) -

[image: example gif]

---

**Did anyone also experience similar problem? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score -1):

Optional still swaps your fonts if the browser decides it's possible to do so. You're telling your browser to use the default font and then change to the custom one if it's possible to do so.

This may be coming late but hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is incorrect information. From the MDN font-display docs:

Optional: Gives the font face an extremely small block period and no swap period.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display